# Parse and substitute markup in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to parse a simple string like:

```
"My name is **NAME**" to "My name is <strong>NAME</strong\>"
```

**Note**:

- Cannot use any external gems, even though markdown gem might have done the job.

Comment: Why are you implementing this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly it should be quite simple:

```
text = "My name is **NAME**"
=> "My name is **NAME**"
text = text.gsub(([a-zA-Z\s]*)(\*\*)([a-zA-Z\s]*)(\*\*)/,"\\1<strong>\\3</strong>")
=> "My name is <strong>NAME</strong>"
```

I've tested it in `irb` with this command `text.gsub(([a-zA-Z\s]*)(\*\*)([a-zA-Z\s]*)(\*\*)/,"\\1<strong>\\3</strong>")`

**UPDATED**

Comment: This doesn't handle the closing tags correctly. i.e. it's putting `<strong>` on both sides of the text to be bolded.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this, if you wish to handle some more cases:

```
class SurroundMarkup
  def initialize(markup_map: {})
    @markup_map = markup_map
  end

  def format(text)
    text.tap do |formatted_text|
      @markup_map.each do |markup, tag|
        formatted_text.gsub!(/#{markup}(?<text>.*?)#{markup}/) do |m|
          start_tag(tag) + $~[:text] + stop_tag(tag)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def start_tag(tag)
    "<#{tag}>"
  end

  def stop_tag(tag)
    "</#{tag}>"
  end
end
```

And you can use as follows:

```
markup_map = {
  /\*\*/ => "strong",
  /\*/ => "i",
}

s = SurroundMarkup.new(markup_map: markup_map)
s.format("My name is **NAME**") #=> "My name is <strong>NAME</strong>"
s.format("*Ruby* is cool") #=> "<i>Ruby</i> is cool"
```